# sending files from iphone app to a local server?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, networking

Need some help please with web related matters since I don't know much about web (more on the software side of things).

Basically, I am developing an iphone app and would like to send data to a local server once in a while (for simplicity, let's just say I want to send this info to my personal computer which will act as the server). This is just some simple data, and I dont care about the format (actually .txt is the best, but I am open to any format which will make it easier - I am just transferring numbers).

What would be the best way to go about this process? A quick step by step explanation would be highly appreciated. From my very basic knowledge I assume that I will need to:

1. setup my Mac as a server (which I think should be done from settings?)
2. Create a URL connection on my app and send the file?

I am probably missing 50 other steps here...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One path is to set up a webDAV server -- you'll have to Google that up, it's far too big a topic to cover here.

To the specific questions you asked:

1) Your mac can become a web server by turning on the WebSharing in preferences, or a file server by turing on fileSharing.  Be sure to set permissions the way you want them.

2) If your mac is a web server, you could write a simple CGI script (perl, ruby, or the like -- this is simple tutorial stuff that's all over the www) that accepts your text as a parameter. From your iPhone app, you'd make an NSURLRequest to a URL similar to:

```
http://192.168.10.1/webPage.html?this+is+the+text+I+want+to+send
```

Of course,  you can get fancier ans use POST requests (the above example is a GET request), but that's going to require more reading.

If you want to transfer files via file sharing, that's a bit more complicted.

What would REALLY help us answer is if you could specify the question a bit more tightly.  As it is, you've asked about a very broad area that covers quite a bit of ground.

Comment: Thank you, Olie, appreciate your answer. What kind of info do you think I missed? To elaborate a bit more, I am developing an app that tracks your location (forever) and sends this info to the server once in a while (let's say when the local file gets too big, or just regularly once a day). This file has only coordinates and time stamps. All the user's data is stored on the server, and can access it back when he wants. Lets assume that I can use my computer as the main server. Is that enough?

Comment: @TommyG: From the sounds of things, your computer needs a permanent address (to be accessed from the app) and to be online 24/7 (so your app will work.)  Then it sounds like you probably want to make an NSURLRequest of the PUT type, with your text file as the data body.  I suggest looking at Apple's sample code for file transfer.  At your computer-end, you'll need to set up a script (perl, ruby or whatever you like) to receive the text and do what you want with it.  This is a fairly complex area; a complete answer would take several pages of tutorial.